# Angular dynamic select values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I've got some dynamically generated `values` in select:

```
<select ng-model="selectedValue" ng-options="o.id as o.name for o in values"></select>
```

And I have `selectedValue` that holds the selected value. I want it to be updated to `null` or `undefined` when the `selectedValue` is no longer present in `values`.

I can clear the `selectedValue` in `$scope.$watch(values)` but is there a better solution?

Basically this situation in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aZjqgkOSP2J1BYFxrUyP?p=preview) is what I want to avoid:

[image: This is what I want to avoid]

I want it to be "Selected value: null" or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a directive that will make the select behave in the way that you'd like.  The HTML would then change to:

```
<select clearable ng-model="selectedValue" ng-options="o.id as o.name for o in values"></select>
```

The JS for the directive would be:

```
app.directive('clearable', ['$parse',function($parse){
  return {
    restrict : 'A',
    scope : {
      'ngModel' : '=',
      'ngOptions' : '@'
    },
    require: ['select','?ngModel'],
    link : function(scope, elem, attr,ctrl){

      // Regex copied from the Angular Source
      var NG_OPTIONS_REGEXP = /^\s*([\s\S]+?)(?:\s+as\s+([\s\S]+?))?(?:\s+group\s+by\s+([\s\S]+?))?\s+for\s+(?:([\$\w][\$\w]*)|(?:\(\s*([\$\w][\$\w]*)\s*,\s*([\$\w][\$\w]*)\s*\)))\s+in\s+([\s\S]+?)(?:\s+track\s+by\s+([\s\S]+?))?$/;
      var match = scope.ngOptions.match(NG_OPTIONS_REGEXP);

      var valuesFn = $parse(match[7]),    //Options list
          key = match[1].split('.')[1];   //Property in options list

      scope.$watch(
        function(){
          // Watch for when the options list changes
          return valuesFn(scope.$parent);
        }, 
        function(newList){
          var isFound, i,
              currentModelVal = scope.ngModel;

          // Iterate through the new list to see if the current value is present
          for(i=0;i<newList.length;i++){
            if (newList[i][key] === currentModelVal){
              isFound = true;
              break;
            }
          }

          // If not found, reset the ng-model value to null
          if (!isFound){
            ctrl[1].$setViewValue(null);
          }
        }
      );

    }
  }  
}]);
```

See the Plunker at http://plnkr.co/edit/yAk9YSoMf88rtTqLXTiI?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can use an option with empty value, and model will be set to empty when no item is selected

check this

```
<option value="">--select--</option>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/66KN7ae0q2v3IUnw47lx?p=preview

Comment: When the selectedValue is not in the values the variable $scope.selectedValue should be cleared/nulled. Your solution is good for showing not selected value but that's not what I want.

Comment: In that case, Why cant you check the value exist in array, inside the function `randomize()`? Is there any other requirement?

Comment: I can do it like that and I'm doing it like that right now. But I'd like to have some better (maybe angular out-of-box) solution because my real world "randomize()" function shouldn't be dependent on the selectedValue. Thank you for your participation!